# c# + check gaps and overlaps in list of tuples

Tags: c#, tuples

I have list of tuples. Each tuple is a min and max value.

I would like to check if in the provided list if any of the ranges are missing or they are overlapping.

This is the definition.

```
 List<Tuple<int, int>> sequences = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
```

example:

```
1. sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10));
   sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(11, 20));
   This is fine

2. sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10));
   sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(13, 20));
   This there are gaps in the sequence

3. sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10));
   sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(10, 20));
   This is an overlapping scenario
```

Currently I am doing

```
  int minrange = 1;
   int maxrange = 20;
   var gaps = Enumerable.Range(minrange, maxrange).Where(i => sequences.All(t => t.Item1 > i || t.Item2 < i));
   var overlapping = Enumerable.Range(minrange, maxrange).Where(i => sequences.Count(t => t.Item1 <= i && t.Item2 >= i) > 1);
```

When the value of sequences are:

```
minrange = 1;
maxrange = 2097152;    
sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10));
    sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(11, 20));
    sequences.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(21, 2097152));
```

In this case my var gaps returns a count which it should not because they are a valid range with no gaps or no overlapping

1. Is this the right way to validate them?
2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to know if there *are* gaps/overlaps, or do you need to *count* the number of such?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might find a data structure like an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree useful.

Comment: @Nate: That's exactly I am trying to achieve with the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a yes or no answer, I believe the following answer the questions:

```
var overlaps =
   (from s1 in sequences from s2 in sequences
    where s1.Item2 >= s2.Item1 && s1.Item1 < s2.Item1 select s1).Any();

var gaps =
    (from s1 in sequences where s1.Item1 > 1 select s1.Item1).Any(
          i => !sequences.Any(
                j => j.Item2 >= i-1&&j.Item1 < i));
```

Hopefully, you can "read" the first query reasonably easily. The second took me some effort, but effectively asks "are there any tuples (other than the one starting at 1) with its lowest value-1 not covered by another tuple in the collection?"

However, if your sets are large, I'd do this in SQL rather than in C# - it feels a more natural place to be asking such "set based" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test that yet, but to find the gaps you could do the following:

```
int lastMax = sequences[0].Item2;
var gaps = sequences.Skip(1).Where(item =>
    {
        bool res = lastMax + 1 < item.Item1;
        lastMax = item.Item2;
        return res;
    });
```

And to find the overlapping items:

```
int lastMax = sequences[0].Item2;
var overlaps = sequences.Skip(1).Where(item =>
    {
        bool res = lastMax >= item.Item1;
        lastMax = item.Item2;
        return res;
    });
```

Both examples assume that your list is already ordered by `Item1`.